# Does a form reload if I call destroy on a control in Form_Terminate instead of Form_Unload?

Tags: forms, memory-leaks, vb6

What happens when I call a destroy on a control in Form_Terminate event instead of the Form_Unload as shown below?

 Does this cause a memory leak? 

 If so, how much? Is it the memory of the whole form itself or that of the control.

```
Private Sub Form_Terminate()
  Set ParentForm = Nothing
  Set ParentFormCtrl = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload()

End Sub
```

Here the "ParentForm" is the form that loads the "Form" above.

Comment: It depends what the `destory()` method does. If it does any interaction with the form's UI then it may cause the form to be reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

`Form_Terminate` is executed after `Form_Unload` but `destroy()` is not a standard VB6 function/sub of any control, and for that, we can't tell if it will cause memory leaks or not. If you have defined this function yourself, then posting the code will help us understand more about your situation.

Comment: +1. See also MSDN topic [Life cycle of Visual Basic (6) Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa242139(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ I've read through that topic. I did not understand this however: "The form has been unloaded, and all references to it released. However, you still have a reference to one of its controls, and this will keep the code part of the form from releasing the memory it's using". What's the code part of the form? Is this connected to GDI?